# AutoCompleteTextView adapter doesn't update. Suggestion coming from an endpoint

Tags: android, kotlin, autocomplete, autocompletetextview

I have an AutoCompleteTextView (et_item_name) with data source coming from an endpoint. Here is the code for setting the initial adapter and reloading it once we receive data from the endpoint.

```
        productSuggestions = ArrayList()
        mSearchSuggestionsAdapter = ArrayAdapter(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, productSuggestions)
        et_item_name.setAdapter(mSearchSuggestionsAdapter)

        et_item_name.threshold = 1
        et_item_name.doAfterTextChanged {
            if (it.toString().trim().length <= 1) {
                productSuggestions.clear()
                mSearchSuggestionsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
            } else {
                mainModel.getProductsAutoCompleteResults(ProductAutoCompleteRequest(10, it.toString(), "SOME_ID")) //this is an endpoint call, which returns fetched results
            }
        }


//Observer
         mainModel.autoCompleteBYOSResult.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { //autoCompleteBYOSResult is MutableLiveData

            productSuggestions.clear()

            var temp: ArrayList<String> = ArrayList()
            it.success?.forEach { temp.add(it.name) }
            productSuggestions.addAll(temp)   //this array has all correct values

            mSearchSuggestionsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() //after this call, this adapter doesn't update, it still shows 0 mObjects when debugging
        })
```

mSearchSuggestionsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() does not update the adapter. It still shows 0 mObjects when in debug mode. The drop down below the AutoCompleteTextView does not appear.

What is the correct way of dynamically updating adapter for AutoCompleteTextView?

Answer (score 0):

So, after trying a lot, I ended up following this article:

https://www.truiton.com/2018/06/android-autocompletetextview-suggestions-from-webservice-call/

```
class AutoSuggestAdapter(context: Context, resource: Int) : ArrayAdapter<String>(context, resource), Filterable {
    private val mlistData: MutableList<String>

    init {
        mlistData = ArrayList()
    }

    fun setData(list: List<String>) {
        mlistData.clear()
        mlistData.addAll(list)
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return mlistData.size
    }

    override fun getItem(position: Int): String? {
        return mlistData[position]
    }

    override fun getFilter(): Filter {
        return object : Filter() {
            override fun performFiltering(constraint: CharSequence?): FilterResults {
                val filterResults = FilterResults()
                if (constraint != null) {
                    filterResults.values = mlistData
                    filterResults.count = mlistData.size
                }
                return filterResults
            }

            override fun publishResults(constraint: CharSequence?, results: FilterResults?) {
                if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                    notifyDataSetChanged()
                } else {
                    notifyDataSetInvalidated()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

//Observer
mainModel.autoCompleteBYOSResult.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            val temp: ArrayList<String> = ArrayList()
            it.success?.forEach { temp.add(it.name) }

            autoSuggestAdapter.setData(temp);
            autoSuggestAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        })


//onCreate
autoSuggestAdapter = AutoSuggestAdapter(context!!, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line)
        et_item_name.threshold = 2
        et_item_name.setAdapter(autoSuggestAdapter)
        et_item_name.doOnTextChanged { text, start, count, after ->
            handler.removeMessages(TRIGGER_AUTO_COMPLETE)
            handler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(TRIGGER_AUTO_COMPLETE, AUTO_COMPLETE_DELAY)

        }

        handler = object : Handler() {
            override fun handleMessage(msg: Message?) {
                if (msg?.what == TRIGGER_AUTO_COMPLETE) {
                    if (et_item_name.text.trim().length > 1) {
                        mainModel.getProductsAutoCompleteResults(ProductAutoCompleteRequest(10, et_item_name.text.trim().toString(), "SOME_ID"))
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

All working now!!